# Working with reference lists in canned workflows

Tags: ocean

I am experimenting with canned workflows and need to know if it's possible to work with lists of domain objects in a reference variable, i.e. reference lists.  Here is some code to illustrate the concept...

```cs
public void Run(Workflow workflow)
{
    ReferenceVariable variable = workflow.InputReferenceVariables.First();
    WorkflowRunner runner = new WorkflowRunner(workflow);
    List<PointSet> pointSets = PetrelProject.Inputs.Selected.OfType<PointSet>().ToList();
    runner.SetInputVariableBinding(variable, pointSets);
    runner.Run();
}
```

This following picture shows the basic workflow.

[image: Workflow]

"Local reference variable 1" is the input variable to which I am assigning the reference list.  I know the example is hacky, but I tried to simplify everything as much as possible.

Anyways, it doesn't seem to work by binding a list, but it also doesn't throw any exceptions.  Nothing happens at all when I run it.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official response from Schlumberger is that reference lists are not yet supported.  There is a work item in their system to provide a reference list API, but it is not yet target for a release.